# How can I connect Excel to my Azure SQL database so I can download and update data?

Tags: excel, azure-sql-database

I read here that I can download data from Azure to Excel:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-connect-excel

But is there a way that I could then update the data in a row and then have that update go back and change the Azure data or can I only do a dump of the data from Azure to Excel one way?

Comment: You can use ADO or if you’ve got a web server, create a web service that will abstract that logic for you. I’m pretty old school so I assume ADO is still the way that sort of thing is achieved.

Comment: Yes it's possible with ADO. You need a fair bit of custom VBA script to do it and you definitely need a primary key on your table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find a tutorial about Update an SQL Table from Excel.

It says you can use Excel SQL Spreads.

SQL Spreads solves some common data management problems for Microsoft SQL Server. It makes it fast and simple to update an SQL table from an Excel spreadsheet. And it gives you the control you need to manage data entered by various users on a collaborative team.

**Summary**:
[image]
[image]
[image]

For more details, please reference [How to Update an SQL Table from Excel](https://sqlspreads.com/2019/02/05/how-to-update-an-sql-table-from-excel/).

I didn't try it, but I think it's useful for you.

Hope this helps.